# mysql reinstall

Tags: mysql

There are similar questions, none of which have solved my given problem so i apologize if I missed something.

I was using `mysqldbcopy` to make a copy of a database when my instance ran out of free space. Mysql crashed and was unable to restart. To free up space I deleted the folder with the new database name from `/var/lib/mysql`. Mysql still would not restart so I removed `/var/lib/mysql` and tried a reinstalling with `sudo mysql_install_db`. This worked, but I could no longer sign in with or without my password, and I could not reset my password.

As a last try, I just did

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
```

but when I go to resinstall, I am getting

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
(Reading database ... 94735 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Output of `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 && sudo apt install -f`:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 && sudo apt install -f
(Reading database ... 94924 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcgi-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl
  mysql-server-core-5.7 python-mysql.connector
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-mysql.connector
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,565 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 94847 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please try `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 && sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @ali76 no dice.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mysql-server mysql-server-5.7` and `sudo apt -f install` to your question

Comment: Ok your problem was solved because `mysql-server` was removed ; you can install mysql again by `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: @ali76 I wish that worked. I've updated the question with the output of the install

Comment: Please try this command `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt install mysql-server` it's may be helpful to run `autoremove` before `install`

Comment: @ali76 Same thing as before `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. I'll note that despite those errors, it looks like the mysql server is running (after I install with that command), but I cannot connect as my previous password does not work (nor does no password)

Comment: Is your msql service enable ? what's the output of `service --status-all | grep mysql`

Comment: ` [ + ]  mysql`        thats all. Edit, I think I got it. I'll add a solution

Comment: So I guess that this issue is happened because of myql is be enabled. So as the first step try to kill and make disable mysql with this  command : `sudo systemctl stop mysql && sudo systemctl disable mysql && sudo killall mysqld` and then try `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

So I tried running `mysqld` in the terminal and saw

```
mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't e$ists.
```

which led me to just create that directort (and update the permissions). I could then

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

I could then start in safe mode

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

and set the password manually

```
USE mysql
UPDATE mysql.user
SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('hunter4')
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
```